# If a list of variables is not empty, echo it inside html

Tags: php, html, arrays, variables

i have multiple variables,

```
$var1 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sizeat',true);
$var2 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'colorat',true);
$var3 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'modelat',true);
```

i want to show the value of the variable inside html if the variable is not empty.

i can do like this for a single variable

```
<?php if(!empty($var1)){ ?>

<span class="pull-right"> <strong><?php echo ($var1) ; ?></strong></span>

<?php ;}?>
```

and thats output the value of var1 inside html only if var1 is not empty.

i want to include all the variables in only 1 statement.

how can i do that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use an array instead of separate variables, then write a `foreach` loop.

Comment: ^ or function implode()

Answer (score 0):

Use an array so you can loop over them.

```
$vars = array('sizeat', 'colorat', 'modelat');

foreach ($vars as $var) {
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $var,true);
    if (!empty($value)) { ?>
        <span class="pull-right"> <strong><?php echo ($value) ; ?></strong></span>
        <?php 
    }
}
```